# How to copy changes from one database to another

Tags: sql-server, database

I have a database and my friend has a copy of the same database. Both of us have made changes to our own copies and now we want to exchange these changes. How are we suppose to do it? we tried the update script but it didn't work ? If there is a fast way to do it I would like to know it .

Comment: Are you talking about data changes or schema changes?

Comment: Schema changes not the data

Comment: I've posted a Redgate-centric answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You set replication before using the databases.
[SQL Server Replication](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms151198.aspx)

Or use a commercial tool like Data Compare if no replication was in place.
e.g. RedGate SQL Data Compare.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I posted the one that I used wishing that someone will find it helpful.

Answer (score 0):

[Redgate SQL Compare](http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-compare/) will do this for you. There's a fully functional 14-day trial which I'd encourage you to try.

If you're looking for more mature processes, you probably want to consider versioning your database changes, which means you share your changes like you would your application code by simply checking the changes in. At Redgate we have [SQL Source Control](http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-source-control/), which integrates with SSMS, or alternatively we have [Redgate ReadyRoll](http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/readyroll/), which integrates with Visual Studio.

Do let me know if you have any questions.

Answer (score -1):

Perform a backup on both databases (yours and your friends).  Then restore each others backups onto your own machine.

Comment: You will only see the changes of the other party and lose your own, if you do it like this. What the OP wants, is to merge the changes of both parties. This does not work with backup/restore.

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes that is true.  In the OP it said exchange, so I took that as taking exactly what the friend had and ignoring anything that was in their own version.